Does having a solid logic foundation necessarily guarantee good common sense faculty?
I am a mathematician by nature, and have a solid core of logic.
I wonder though, does this necessarily mean I have good common sense?
Can it be possible to have one of these without the other?

One could argue that "common sense" also involves a good understanding of emotion, and "street smarts". Having an advanced intellect doesn't help with either of those, and the bumbling professor, who is messy, and a nerd with little social skills, is a stereotype for a reason. If you like the direction I am going, let me know, and I would be glad to put the above into a fuller answer, explaining what I wrote more formally and in detail (if I get the time)

In my experience, "common sense" usually includes whatever the person saying it wants to assert without evidence; or they assert that their opinion is widely held, without evidence of its popularity; or they assert that people who disagree with the opinion are deficient in some way. I'm not convinced it is a useful epistemological category.

No. Good arguments have to be both sound and valid. Logic only provides validity, for common sense one also needs sound judgment and practical intuition. The stereotype of clumsy mathematician with his head in the clouds is there for a reason.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"I am a mathematician by nature" What do you mean "by nature"? I don't think you can be mathematician by nature.

Logic and reasoning only work when given correct inputs. Otherwise, garbage in, garbage out.
Stepping outside of math and into real life problems, a correct logical reasoning must be probabilistic and incorporate probabilities of the prior assumptions it is based on being wrong. However, these probabilities are generally not known precisely.
If the system gets complex enough, for example a civilisation, no one has any idea what the prior assumptions even are, and if some have ideas others will strongly disagree with them. The only way to know would be to run actual life-size tests, which is usually not possible, although there are exceptions, for example the results of communism are well known experimentally.
So the probability of the chain of logic resting on a wrong assumption hidden somewhere is not known precisely either. Overconfidence in logic based on firmly held (but dubiously proved) priors can lead to catastrophic failures, for example the COVID injections.
As someone familiar with things going horribly wrong said, it's the unknown unknowns that get you.
Pure logic tends to work well in pocket universes where the rules are simple, or in situations where the approximations that must be done to reduce the complexity of the real world down to something manageable are valid.
This is Chesterton's fence: don't try to change something unless you understand it. But sometimes, understanding it is a difficult problem...
Common sense sidesteps the problem by being a heuristic biased towards safety. One can view common sense as a result of natural selection in the genetic and memetic space: those who did not possess enough of it did not transmit their genes or their culture. So perhaps we should do as those who survived did. The tradeoff for reducing risk is that it stifles innovation.
The whole point of common sense is that it is software that can run on the average brain, so it does not require a high IQ, or an academic education in epistemology, philosophy, or logic. Not being able to explain why the rules of common sense are the way they are is part of the deal: if everyone had to know at all times the complete logical chain between root causes and choices of actions, it would take so much work nothing else would get done and we would all starve. Thus criticizing common sense based on this is simply lack of wisdom.

In human psychology, commonly intelligence and education combined typically lead to common sense, but not necessarily so. Obvious counter examples are various personality disorders or extreme traumatising personal circumstances.
Another typical example are selective application of common sense. Cults and religions function on the mind by suspension of common sense, in the name of faith.
Such as imagining a wrathful, infallible, wise and omniscient god that regards humanity with scorn. A god that visits plague and destruction upon nations for not freeing one ethnicity from forced exile. And then humanity seized the only son of that god, tortures and kills that son (A kind a Peaceful ray on sunshine, that one). And the same god then says: "oh, err, alright, I'll love all of ya now, we're good. My bad for all those firstborns. Also the flood, but I had a bad headache that day, I must be excused. Bygones, eh?". Cults will then throw a lot of theology at people to make them suspend common sense about that story. Cults will say "God works in mysterious ways" to explicitly beg for suspension of common sense, they'll also try to indoctrinate humans as children before common sense is fully matured, or withhold "advanced scripture" to only expose members with sufficient entanglement in the cult.
Common sense is also often suspended for political matters touching personal safety and freedom, such as gun laws, abortion and marriage laws, drug laws, and so on. Like for faith, society accepts a certain selectivity about when to apply or suspend common sense.
So various circumstances can cause otherwise intelligent and educated people to lack common sense in general or to suspend common sense about certain topics.
However IMHO the proverbial mathematical genius who is socially awkward and clumsy in matters of the daily life though is not an example for lack of common sense. It may just be a lack of practice and interest, which is an entirely different thing.


I am a mathematician by nature, and have a solid core of logic.

A solid core of logic?! We all do. Humans are all logical, for it is not possible to survive in the harsh environment of planet Earth without being logical.
Perhaps you mean that you have a training in formal logic. If so, unfortunately, a training in formal logic does not guarantee that your reasonings be logical.

I wonder though, does this necessarily mean I have good common sense?

Common sense is something else. Literally, common sense is by definition the capacity shared by human beings to all understand the same things in the same way. Common sense is more prevalent than what some people try to make it out to be. Just think of some people gathered around a tree in some garden. Would most of them not agree that there is indeed a tree?
Agreeing that there is a tree at some place requires a logical capacity, but this also requires perception and memory, not just a logical capacity.

Can it be possible to have one of these without the other?

Any academic activity requires a logical capacity. For that matter, any intelligent activity requires a logical capacity. In fact, if we didn't have a logical capacity, many if not most of our voluntary actions would be absurd. I don't see many people doing really absurd things.
I also don't think that most mathematicians throughout history had any prior training in formal logic. Doesn't seem to have prevented the development of mathematics.
